# File Structure in Django

Tags: python, django, backend

I am learning Django and making an ecommerce website. My File Structure is as follows:
[![My project File Structure][1]][1]

Now I am uploading some pictures but could not able to access in the web.

```
{% load static %}    
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src='{% static "images/aws.png" %}' class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
```

The above example is of an part of an carousal. Please help where I am missing something. How to give link to images in my web.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eio3H.jpg

Comment: I think you must add this to urls.py  `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: Yes I added these lines to my project urls file.

Comment: try and add a fuller path? `"media/static/images/aws.png"` ?

Comment: I did that but still images are not loading

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating the `settings.py` file. I added this line:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/static")
```